# How to use sagesilent (or verbatim) environment in pgffor loops?

Tags: verbatim, sagetex, pgffor

I want to create different versions of an exam paper and corresponding sample solutions using `sagetex`. I need to assign variables for more involved computations, so I am reliant on the `sagesilent` environment. However, this environment seems to be a type `verbatim` environment and that seems to be incompatible with `\foreach` loops the the `pgffor` package provides. The latter is needed to generate the different versions of the exam.

Error messages look like this:

> ERROR: Paragraph ended before \verbatim@ was complete.

Is there a way to make the two packages work together? Ideally, a solution would optionally allow the expansion of macros in the `sagesilent` environment, [like in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222792/19500).

An MWE example is given below (without macro expansion).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x/\y in {3/4,5/6,7/8} {

  The product of $\x$ and $\y$ is $\sage{\x*\y}$. % this works

  % but not this: (the assignment z= cannot be done in \sage{})
  \begin{sagesilent}
    z=2*9
  \end{sagesilent}

}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I should add that I did look into different loop options, e.g., using latex3 like suggested [in this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133608). This didn't work either.

Comment: Why do you need to mix the two packages? It seems like sagetex can do everything by itself.

Comment: I am actually planning to use a non-public package supporting dedicated question banks, and this works by storing exam questions in macros that can be pulled in later as needed. `pgffor` is a placeholder for that. I guess my main problem is that I need sagetex environments that can be stored in a macro and be evaluated (by sage) only once the macro is expanded. For this, verbatim-type environments seem to be the wrong path.

Comment: I don't think that it can be done; but I don't know enough to say it can't be done. If you aren't able to get a response here, you might try posting a question at [AskSagemath](http://ask.sagemath.org/questions/). It seems like Python with sagetex should be able to do everything by, say, storing each exam question as a string in sagesilent and printing it as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. I'd really like this to work with this exam package I mentioned, so ideally without any external tools like python. I remain hopeful that someone comes up with an idea.

Answer (score 0):

One way (easy to understand and use only public API, but hacky) is to use `exec()`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
def execreturnempty(s):
    exec(s, globals())
    return ""
\end{sagesilent}

\foreach \x/\y in {3/4,5/6,7/8} {

  The product of $\x$ and $\y$ is $\sage{\x*\y}$. % this works

  a\sagestr{execreturnempty('z=2*9')}b
}

\sage{z}  % double check the code is executed correctly
\end{document}
```

How it works is obvious.

An alternative is to define such a `\sageexec` command, but this implementation relies on how the commands are implemented internally in the `sagetex` package.
(to write the code, learn TeX programming, then read the source code of `sagetex` package and adapt the definition of `sageblock`)

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}

% ======== begin magic ========
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sageexec}[1]{%
\ST@wsf{%
_st_.current_tex_line = \the\inputlineno^^J%
_st_.blockbegin()^^Jtry: #1^^J%
except:^^J %intentional space
_st_.goboom(\the\inputlineno)^^J_st_.blockend()}}
\makeatother
% ======== end magic ========

\foreach \x/\y in {3/4,5/6,7/8} {

  The product of $\x$ and $\y$ is $\sage{\x*\y}$. % this works

  \sageexec{z=2*9}
}

\sage{z}  % double check the code is executed correctly
\end{document}
```